# Combining a kinship matrix and pedigree data into a new kinship matrix

Tags: out-of-memory, simulation

I am running a very large simulation, trying to simulate kinship of a constant size population of 500  along 50,000 iterations. In each iteration one individual dies and one is born.

The function PED of the package KINSHIP2 does the job easily for a medium size of iterations. However, once I increase the number of iterations into tens of thousands, the system throws me out due to a memory problem. This is quite reasonable, as for N simulations the system has to calculate approximately 0.5*(500+N)^2 pairwise relationships.

I realized that if I stop the run every k iterations (on a "*middle time point*") and calculate the pedigree function at this point, I could probably throw out all of the dead individuals, and keep running my simulation from that point with a much less heavy data load. However, I cannot find any existing function which would take in both the "*middle time point*" kinship matrix, and the pedigree matrix developed since that *Middle time point*, combine them and calculate the updated kinship matrix.

Any suggestions?
Thank you so much